# Why does replacing drive with a dd clone cause machine to hang at boot?

Tags: boot, grub, dd, clone

I have a home-brew media server based on a 800MHz Intel Atom with two big LVM drives and Debian 9 on a 250GB 2.5" drive. The latter is showing bad blocks, so I am intending to replace it.

I booted from a Debian live CD and dd'd the entire 250GB disk surface onto a new WD Blue 1TB drive with `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdd` with the new disk connected to a USB-SATA interface. Then I fitted the drive into the media server replacing the 250GB one. The machine hangs on boot, just after printing the drive ID and before the boot loader starts. The boot loader was grub legacy. I booted from the live CD and chrooted into the clone which appeared to work fine. So I mounted the LVM volumes, and installed grub2 to the new /dev/sda which claimed to have been successful. But booting from the new HD still locks the machine up as before. I've also run `update-initramfs -u -k all`, `grub-install`, `update-grub` and whathaveyou as one would expect.

I then tried out [this boot repair cd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) which also claimed success but made no difference to the result. The machine hangs early after power-up.

I was warned about not having a small /boot partition near the front of the drive, so I've created one now. No difference. I also tried leaving a 6MB gap before the first partition, aligning to 4K sectors and so on, repeating the whole grub install and boot-repair-disk attempt every time. Every time: won't boot, crashes before you can get into the BIOS screen, but boot from CD and you can chroot into it, so the data seems intact.

Retrofitting the old drive works just fine (for the moment).

This is a very simple machine, MBR msdos-style boot, no EFI, only one OS installed.

Is there a good reason the machine won't boot from a clone of an old 250GB drive made onto a 1TB drive? How does it know? The drive ID doesn't appear anywhere in `/boot/grub` that I can find. It's all UUIDs.

The old drive has 512B physical sectors, and then new one has 4096B ones, but it has 512B emulation, right?

Here's some of the output from the boot repair CD running against the new drive.

```
Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *      1,036,288   477,345,791   476,309,504  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         477,347,840 1,953,525,167 1,476,177,328   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         477,349,888   489,932,799    12,582,912  83 Linux
/dev/sda3              12,288     1,036,287     1,024,000  83 Linux


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1                    3415,628,048,06415,628,048,031 Logical Volume Manager (LVM) partition (Linux)

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set

Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition  Attrs   Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdc1                 2,048 5,860,532,223 5,860,530,176 Logical Volume Manager (LVM) partition (Linux)

Attributes: R=Required, N=No Block IO, B=Legacy BIOS Bootable, +=More bits set

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/mapper/exported-archive 4b899a61-2f1c-4cd8-bc32-ce435912ba87   ext3       
/dev/mapper/exported-media 36a5370f-d49a-4da3-9bc8-fefa0d005f4f   ext3       
/dev/mapper/exported-photos af677e44-2a83-4aba-8b37-c38c3b07a10b   ext3       
/dev/mapper/exported-web 27040136-28bf-464d-9802-c20511ad661f   ext3       
/dev/sda1        7788ea31-5e63-4869-a80e-40c99c6128b3   ext3       
/dev/sda3        6f547317-4688-435f-a69d-787bf7262f29   ext3       boot
/dev/sda5        a311a5cb-4f03-4930-a028-bf87b4dd8e55   swap       swap
/dev/sdb1        yGbmYE-Lvk1-8lZj-0xQz-u57b-L1sV-0RjV66 LVM2_member 
/dev/sdc1        ShaGRu-GqRZ-4fS3-k0zp-g5x4-5Kae-uLoC9o LVM2_member 
/dev/sr0         2017-10-29-01-25-15-00                 iso9660    Boot-Repair-Disk 32bit
/dev/zram0       a9802c34-25bd-4f6f-b3e5-d75c62fe8adc   swap       
/dev/zram1       5ea34823-7d6a-4ac5-bb49-7fa9c8bbecea   swap       
/dev/zram2       dcc2c96c-1f33-4604-b5ac-d62964731bd4   swap       
/dev/zram3       0eb6d924-359e-4fed-b904-788ce185bb0a   swap
```

Comment: you may have forbidden to copy the boot sector ? (separatelly) from `dd if=/dev/drivesource of=/drivedestination bs=512 count=1`

Comment: I didn't do that, but I was copying from /dev/sda to /dev/sdd so that would include the boot sector wouldn't it? I should make a few edits to make that more clear.

Comment: In fact, the first attempt I used a dump and restore pipe like a grown-up. Copying the whole surface with dd was really a final act of desperation. I'm hoping it's not a 4096B physical sector thing. I would probably be in new motherboard territory.

Comment: @NickBailey. Yes dd'ing from /dev/sda to /dev/sdd, if done correctly, should have included sector 0.  What was the full `dd` command that you used?

Comment: @NickBailey, I would not clone from a drive with 512 byte sectors to a drive with 4096 byte sectors. Even if it might work, it would not perform as well as it would with the correct sector size. I suggest that you 1. have good **backups** of all 'own' files and tweaks and then 2. Create a partition table and let the installer make a fresh installation. Make sure it will use correct 4096 byte sectors, and finally 3. copy your 'own' files to where you want them and install the server tools that you need.

Comment: fpmurphy: I used dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdd (having checked they were the right drives!).

Comment: sudodus: I got here having first partitioned nicely and dumped | restored the partition onto the new drive. Same result. The dd solution is not my preferred one; more of a sign of desperation. I understand it'll probably wreck the performance. I've certainly got a full backup now: I can chroot into the new drive and see everything there! But yes, I had a backup :) The thing that's surprising me is that the machine won't boot at all when the new drive is plugged in. Total lock-up. Boot from DVD and hot-plug the HD, and you can chroot to the new drive and see everything's there.

Comment: @NickBailey, The problem might be the different physical sector size. I have cloned from a smaller to a bigger drive several times, and the cloned copy has worked just like the original one. I BIOS mode, you need not fix anything (but in UEFI mode you must repair the backup partition table at the tail end of the drive). -- But it is important that only one of the drives, the source or the target of the cloning, but not both, is connected, when you intend to boot. If you have booted with both drives connected, one of the systems could have been damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Prelim

I assume youve backed up — redundancy proportional to the value of the data!
`dd`​s as well as tarballs

So… You did a full-device `dd` uh…uh.
Double that for badblock source disk. And again for quite different source and target disk architectures

Following are slight improvements (for completeness only) I dont really expect real benefits. What I recommend is below these

## Partition dds

Manually partition the new disk; `dd` each partition individually

## Partition copys

Manually partition the new disk; mkfs; high level copy the file system.
`cp -a` has given me trouble where `tar c... source|tar x... target` has worked

But I assume you've tried the above and its not worked. So…

## Does the new disk work?

To try just install a fresh new debian on the new disk. Does it work?

If no the of course we are dealing with a completely different problem

Assuming yes then

## Side-by-side

[For simplicity I am assuming you avoid the LV stuff]

- When installing the new OS (above)  manually partition and choose for *two* root systems — one for current (new) installation one for (copy of) your old. Lets LABEL them DebCurrent DebOld
- Proceed with new install into DebCurrent
- Copy over old disk root to Debold
- Re-point `/etc/fstab` of Debold
- [Assuming the DebCurrent boots]
- At the time of booting

  - Enter grub prompt
  - Open up the working stanza for DebCurrent
  - Hand edit to point to DebOld; Try to boot

But… (I'm guessing) the problem is still there. And its a

## Hardware Mismatch Issue

Maybe the problem is that

- Motherboard is old (MBR-BIOS)
- Disk is new — prefers gpt

IOW *the default* is:

```
old: BIOS-MB + MBR-disk
new: EFI-MB + gpt-disk
```

No possibility of mix-n-match, ie in the windows world this is not solvable without shelling out more bucks for a new EFI MB.

However in the linux world you can use [a gpt disk with a bios-MB](https://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2012/10/the-difference-between-booting-mbr-and-gpt-with-grub/) 
The key thing there is that you need to create a BBP — a tiny 1MB special bios boot partition near the beginning of the disk.

You can do that with [parted](https://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2012/10/booting-large-gpt-disks-without-efi/) though Id recommend all gpt things to be done with [gdisk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/partitioning)

## Added later

Making the bbp

I strongly recommend that for gpt disks the actual partitioning be done with gdisk. This keeps alignment well. Thereafter marking the type as BBP may be easier with (g)parted. Note the parted and gdisk links above

Comment: Thanks, Rusi! Yes, sorry to mention dd-ing disks in stack overflow ;) Asreply above, I tried to behave like a grown-up at first and did a dump restore into fresh partitions then grub at first. I don't understand how the disk "prefers" gpt? Does the BBP have to be an actual partition or can it be empty space? I left 6MB before part-1 having aligned them to 4K in case that was it (using gparted on a laptop with a USB-SATA interface). I can chroot into the new hd by booting from CD and hot plugging: the disk works. Will test on a machine at work and report. Maybe old MB won't talk SATA-3 (?)

Comment: dd: Whatever works!!! BBP: Added clarification in reply. Yes it must be made and marked as such because that tells grub "you are free to mess around in here"

Comment: «Old MB wont talk SATA-3»: Easy enough to verify (without multiplying variables) by: Fresh-install on Old MB+New Disk. Dont you think?

Comment: Sure. If I do it at work it'll look like I'm working ;) I'll do a bit more testing and report back. Thanks for the comprehensive answer and the heads up on the gpt. Hoping it doesn't have to be partition 1, but p3 /boot is already before P1 so it needs a tidy up anyway.

Comment: In that case kindly upvote!

Comment: was quite right: in this case it was a **hardware mismatch issue** I have no total solution, but the new drive is now in an enclosure connected via USB. This ended up being bootable into the original media-server system, or a fresh install of Debian 9 with a desktop, selected from the grub menu at boot time. I also found some reports about SATA3 being incompatible with SATA1 from 2011. It isn't, but the symptoms were the same, so I'm blaming the 4k sectors for this. In the 2011 case, a bios upgrade resolved the issue, but I don't think that's available to me.

Comment: So where's the working grub now?

Comment: Still booting from MBR of the new drive. Seems happy over USB. The machine locks up if the drive is plugged in to either the MB SATA controller or the additional PCI slot one. It locks up so early in the boot sequence you can't even get to the bios screen. The bad blocks on the old drive were actually in the swap partition, so I've essentially got a mirror of the entire system now. Since we've unfortunately had to start running Plex Media Server because the "smart" TV isn't, I shall end up rebuilding the machine in the medium term, so that's a solution for now.

Comment: Remember "dpkg --get-selections" to speed up making a new install replica of old. And thanks the accept even tho not exactly the solution